# I aggregated multiple data frames in a list. Each df in the new list has 2cols:"Group.1" & "x". I want assign each x column the name of its data frame

Tags: r, list, variables, aggregate, rename

I aggregated multiple data frames that were within an input list as (providentially) suggested by Andrew Gustar at [lapply aggregate columns in multiple dataframes R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721243/lapply-aggregate-columns-in-multiple-dataframes-r) .

Here the code, copied from the above mentioned page.

Creation of the data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Count = c(1,2,3), ID = c("A","A","C"))
df2 <- data.frame(Count = c(1,1,2), ID = c("C","B","C"))
dfList <- list(df1,df2)

> head(dfList)
[[1]]
  Count ID
1     1  A
2     2  A
3     3  C

[[2]]
  Count ID
1     1  C
2     1  B
3     2  C
```

Aggregation by the "ID" column (as suggested by Andrew Gustar)

```
dfList_agg<-lapply(dfList, function(i) {
  aggregate(i[,1], by=list(i[,2]), FUN=sum)
})

dflist_agg

[[1]]
  Group.1 x
1       A 3
2       C 3

[[2]]
  Group.1 x
1       B 1
2       C 3
```

As you can see above, each data frame in the output list has a column named "Group.1" (containing the BY column), and the other named "x" (containing the summarized data).

Instead, I need to assign each "x" column the name of its corresponding data frame. Referring to the example, I want both columns named "x" to get the distinct names "df1" and "df2", in the output list.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance,

Fabio

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example of your data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have a named `list`, then use `Map` to do the assignment

```
dfList_agg <- Map(function(dat, y) {
        names(dat)[names(dat)=='x'] <- y
        dat},
            dfList_agg, names(dfList_agg))
dfList_agg
#$df1
#  Group.1 df1
#1       A   3
#2       C   3

#$df2
#  Group.1 df2
#1       B   1
#2       C   3
```

#### data

```
dfList_agg <- list(structure(list(Group.1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("A", 
"C"), class = "factor"), x = c(3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(Group.1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("B", "C"
    ), class = "factor"), x = c(1, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -2L
    ), class = "data.frame"))
names(dfList_agg) <- c('df1', 'df2')
```

Comment: Great, thank you! 

Perhaps you could suggest some 'for dummies' reading about the `Map` function and its `funprog` family in R?